# How to perform simple addition in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, hana

I want to perform simple addition operation using a stored procedure:

```
create procedure "KABIL"."ADD"
(  out c int)
as
begin
declare a int := 5;
declare  b int := 6 ;
c = :a + :b;
end;
```

Comment: What is your question? Is this SAP HANA related or generally about stored procedures?

Answer (score 2):

you can also pass the int or float using paramiter

```
create  procedure KABIL(@a float, @b float)
as
begin
declare @sum varchar(4)
set @sum=cast((@a+@b) as VARCHAR)
print 'the sum of '+cast(@a as varchar) + ' and ' + cast(@b as varchar) + ' is ' + cast((@a+@b) as VARCHAR)
print @sum
END
```

pass two value in KABIL(float,float) value

Answer (score 0):

This is the way adding two number in sql. here that numbers pass as parameter and print output if want you can return output.

```
create procedure KABIL(@a int,@b int)
as
begin
declare @c int
set @c=@a+@b
print @c
end
```

This is way to execute stored procedure

```
exec KABIL 2,6
```